# Permission denied error when using apt and apt-get as root on raspbian

Tags: raspbian, apt, permissions, root

I keep getting an error when I use apt or apt-get as a root user or using sudo with the default pi account.

```
Ign:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease

Ign:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease

Err:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch Release
  System error resolving 'raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80' - getaddrinfo (13: Permission denied)

Err:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch Release
  System error resolving 'archive.raspberrypi.org:80' - getaddrinfo (13: Permission denied)

Reading package lists... Done

E: The repository 'http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

E: The repository 'http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what repositories do you have addressed in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. But it seems you have a **Raspbian** and a **Debian** repository addressed. This is not a good idea except do you really know what you are doing (sorry, but it seems not to be the case ;-).

The `Permission denied` is to the remote web sites `raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80` and `archive.raspberrypi.org:80`. This has nothing to do with the local superuser **root**. It shows in conjunction with the other messages that there is no more a valid repository accessable.

The default entries for the repositories on **Raspbian Stretch** are:

```
rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi

rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

I suggest to use these entries.

Comment: Currently I have:
"deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi" in my sources.list. Is there another file I should look for?

Comment: @Craig Yes, there is another file to look for as shown in my answer. Check `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`.

Comment: > (sorry, but it seems not to be the case ;-). ya...god forbid someone play around with their pi to learn more